# Hello world android - creation with errors

Tags: android, compiler-errors, r.java-file, main-activity

I'm trying to create my first app with Android but I've encountered some problems.

Following a tutorial and making:
new android application -> blank activity

The default result should be:

[image]

With MainActivity.java and R.Java inside it.

But instead I've got this:

[image]

There are a lot of errors and the R.Java file is missing.

I can obtain a result similar to the tutorial one (with no errors), creating a new android application and unchecking create activity, but this time MainActivity.java under src is totally missing.
Maybe I could copy the MainActivity.java of the first project and put into the second one, but I prefer understand why it doesn't work.

Thanks for the help.
Best regards.

Comment: you need import this library to your application

Comment: did you try Project > Clean

Answer (score 0):

its import library problem

Right click on you application----->Android

under library view ,

check if you have this red error then remove the library and add it again

[image]

Comment: Right click on Prova1 ?
Then I have Android Tools -> Add support Libray.

The option "Android" is under refactor.

Comment: no sir , its prefer to delete support Library v4 in Prova1  , then just add it as i mention above